# Shoutout data error swift

Tags: ios, swift, stream

Im trying to get html data from shoutoutStream , actually currently playing title...
I'm new at swift programming so i really need a help.

This is what i've tryied but still getting error:

> ICY 404 Resource Not Found
>   icy-notice1:
> SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8
>   icy-notice2:The resource requested was not found

```
 let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://s5.voscast.com:8220/7.html")!)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        var usedEncoding = NSASCIIStringEncoding
        print(usedEncoding)// Some fallback value
        if let encodingName = response?.textEncodingName {
            let encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(encodingName))
            if encoding != UInt(kCFStringEncodingInvalidId) {

                usedEncoding = encoding
            }
        }
        if let myString = String(data: data!, encoding: usedEncoding) {
            print("this is my string: \(myString)")
        } else {
            print("failed to decode data")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

Please help me , i'm sooo frustrated already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891900/shoutcast-fetch-request-denied-everytime-with-404 Duplicate

Comment: thanks men,  but how can i get that data in swift ?

Comment: While creating the URL Request, u need to include the `UserAgent: SHOUTcast Song Status` in the header field. `request.setValue("SHOUTcast Song Status", forHTTPHeaderField:"UserAgent")`

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot!